# I'm New to this: a carousel that displays images with a random quote generator overlay and it only works on the first image... but then?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

'The generator works and displays over the first image but I lose it on the second and third then it appears again with a different quote over the first slide again the way it should and I'm lost as to why' I've tried numerous things to figure this out and know it's probably very simple. I looked at ajax and jquery but still couldn't find the answer.

```js
//Begin the Random Quote function of 'generateQuote'
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var myCarousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");

       myCarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function(){
        generateQuote();
       document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = 'myCarousel';
    
     });
     });

        const generateQuote = function() {
     const quotes = [
     {
         quote: "Do not pity the dead, Harry. Pity the living, and, above all those who live without             love.",
        author: "Albus Dumbledore"
    },
    {
        quote: "It is impossible to manufacture or imitate love",
        author: "Horace Slughorn"
    },
    {
        quote: "Being different isn't a bad thing. It means that you are brave enough to be yourself.",
        author: "Luna Lovegood"
    },
    {
        quote: "If you want to know what a man’s like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.",
        author: "Sirius Black"
    },
    {
        quote: "Never trust anything that can think for itself if you can’t see where it keeps its brain.",
        author: "Arthur Weasley"
    },
    {
        quote: "Every human life is worth the same, and worth saving.",
        author: "Kingsley Shacklebolt"
    },
    {
        quote: "Have a biscuit, Potter.",
        author: "Minerva McGonagall"
    },
    {
        quote: "Happiness can be found even in the darkest of times, if one only remembers to turn on the light.",
        author: "Albus Dumbledore"
    },
    {
        quote: "Socks are Dobby’s favorite, favorite clothes, sir!",
        author: "Dobby"
    }
];

    let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    document.getElementById("quotes").innerHTML = quotes[arrayIndex].quote;
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = quotes[arrayIndex].author;

}
```

'The myBox and text class align the quotes in the upper right of the image and it works like it' 'should but just on the first image then I get nothing until it cycles thru again. Thanks.'

```html
    <!-- The Start of the main Carousel-->

    <div class="container-lg my-3">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              
              <!--The Quotes for the first image-->
                
                <div class="mybox">
                    
                   
                    <img id="generate" src="images/mockup1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 1">
                        
                    
                <div class="text">
                    
                    <p id="quotes"></p>
                    <p id="author"></p>

                </div></div>
                
                <!-- End of the first image Quotes-->

            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">

              <!--The Quotes for the second image-->
                <div class="mybox">

                    <img id="generate" src="images/mockup2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 2">

                    <div class="text">
                        
                        <p id="quotes"></p>
                        <p id="author"></p>
    
                    </div></div>
              <!-- End of Second image-->

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">

              <!--The Quotes for the Third image-->
                <div class="mybox">
                    
                 <img id="generate3" src="images/mockup3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Slide 3">

                    <div class="text">
                        
                        <p id="quotes"></p>
                        <p id="author"></p>
    
                    </div></div>
              <!-- End of Third image-->

              
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
     </div>
    
    

     </div>
```

Comment: The ID values should be unique in each page. Right now, you have multiple ID attributes with the same value (#quotes, #author). JS will find the first ID and use that. It will disregard any subsequent elements with the same ID.

Comment: OH THANK YOU!! It works like a charm now!! I have been trying to over think it for the last few days.

Answer (score -1):

There appears to be an issue in the following line:

`myCarousel.addEventListener("slide.bs.carousel", function(){`

You have passed a CSS selector `slide.bs.carousel` as the first argument to `addEventListener`. This should be the event it's listening for, e.g., `click`.

Comment: No, this is a proper event name for the carousel. Check the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#events